# SCSS Animation Bug: Heart starts animations on page refresh due to :checked and :not(:checked) selectors

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a piece of code that is causing me some trouble.

For my "like" animation, I have a selector that checks whether my input field is "checked" or not. Everything works fine, BUT when the page is refreshed, the heart starts the animations due to the :checked and :not(:checked) selectors ( this is only logical).

My question is: how can I achieve these animations without this animation bug? Without using javascript.

I know the naming of my classes isn't great, i'm still learning

```css
.fa-solid {
  position: relative;
}

.fa-regular {
  position: absolute;
}

.heart-icon,
.heart-icon-solid {
  font-size: 100px;
}

.heart-icon-solid {
  transform-origin: bottom;
  transform: scale(0);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #9356DC 0%, #FF79DA 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

/*.like__container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}*/
.like__checkbox {
  display: none;
}
.like__checkbox:not(:checked) + .like__container .heart-icon:hover {
  animation: 1.5s ease 0s infinite beat;
}
.like__checkbox:checked + .like__container .heart-icon-solid {
  animation: like 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.87, 0.01, 0.38, 1.01) forwards;
}
.like__checkbox:checked + .like__container .heart-icon {
  animation: like--BG 1s ease forwards;
}
.like__checkbox:not(:checked) + .like__container .heart-icon-solid {
  animation: unlike 0.5s ease forwards;
}
.like__checkbox:not(:checked) + .like__container .heart-icon {
  animation: nounlike 1s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes beat {
  0%, 50%, 100% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  30%, 80% {
    transform: scale(0.82, 0.85);
  }
}
@keyframes like {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes like--BG {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes unlike {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css"
        integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer">
</head>



<input type="checkbox" id="like__input" class="like__checkbox">
<label for="like__input" class="like__container">
    <i class="fa-regular fa-heart heart-icon card__content--heart"></i>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-heart heart-icon-solid card__content--heart--filled"></i>
</label>


<!-- <input type="checkbox" id="likeCheckbox">
<label for="likeCheckbox" class=container>
<i class="fa-regular fa-heart heart-icon"></i>
<i class="fa-solid fa-heart heart-icon-solid"></i>
</label> -->
```

[Link to my codepen for this](https://codepen.io/MoonstruckLucii/pen/LYqLvqK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here relies on the assumption that you actually need the animations on click and hover only. Therefore I'm using `:focus` to catch clicks.

Note that you need `tabindex` on `label` to make it have `:focus`.

Also I changed order of some elements and CSS  rules.

```css
.fa-solid {
  position: absolute;
}

.fa-regular {
  position: relative;
}

.heart-icon,
.heart-icon-solid {
  font-size: 100px;
}

.heart-icon-solid {
  transform-origin: bottom;
  transform: scale(0);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #9356DC 0%, #FF79DA 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

/*
.like__container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
*/

.like__checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.like__checkbox:not(:checked)+.like__container .heart-icon:hover, .like__checkbox:not(:checked)+.like__container:focus .heart-icon:hover
{
  animation: 1.5s ease 0s infinite beat;
}

.like__checkbox:checked+.like__container:focus .heart-icon-solid {
  animation: like 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.87, 0.01, 0.38, 1.01) forwards;
}

.like__checkbox:not(:checked)+.like__container:focus .heart-icon-solid {
  animation: unlike .75s 50ms ease forwards;
}

.like__checkbox:checked+.like__container:focus .heart-icon {
  animation: like--BG 1s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes beat {
  0%,
  50%,
  100% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  30%,
  80% {
    transform: scale(0.82, 0.85);
  }
}

@keyframes like {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes like--BG {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes unlike {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css">
</head>



<input type="checkbox" id="like__input" class="like__checkbox">
<label for="like__input" class="like__container" tabindex="0">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-heart heart-icon-solid card__content--heart--filled"></i>
    <i class="fa-regular fa-heart heart-icon card__content--heart"></i>
</label>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer, Much appreciated, will look into the how it works as well rather than mindlessly copying so i can know for the future